# Is there an option to readfile() but only a range of bytes of a binary file?

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to stream files from the server to my computer, all working good with no issues, now i need to stream only a part of a binary file, which means only the bytes range of for example 1000-2000.

I'd like to add the range ($from, $to) to the URL the same way i'm doing with the $filename.

thank you

```
<?php
$file_url = ''.$_GET['filename'];

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); `
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" .   
basename($file_url) . "\""); 

readfile($file_url);
?>`
```

Comment: No, you'll need to read 999 bytes and throw it away, then read the next 1000 and output it:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php Or read it all and slice it up: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and output it.

Comment: `fopen()`, `fseek()`, and `fread()`

Comment: May I add `fclose()` to the above list of useful functions :)

Comment: Also forgot about http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php